# Error: The 'elasticsearch' backend requires the installation of 'requests'. How do I fix it?

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I´m having a issue when I ran "python manage.py rebuild_index" in my app supported by haystack and elasticsearch.

Python 2.7
Django version 1.6.2
Haystack 2.1.0
Elasticsearch 1.0

Please see the error that is appearing:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "manage.py", line 10, in 
>      execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 399, in > execute_from_command_line
>      utility.execute()
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 392, in > execute
>      self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in >run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **options.**dict**)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/rebuild_index.py", line 15, in handle
>       call_command('clear_index', **options)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 159, in call_command
>       return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/management/commands/clear_index.py", line 48, in handle
>       backend = connections[backend_name].get_backend()
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/utils/loading.py", line 98, in **getitem**
>       self._connections[key] = load_backend(self.connections_info[key]['ENGINE'])(using=key)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/utils/loading.py", line 51, in load_backend
>       return import_class(full_backend_path)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/utils/loading.py", line 18, in import_class
>       module_itself = importlib.import_module(module_path)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
>       **import**(name)
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/haystack/backends/elasticsearch_backend.py", line 21, in 
>       raise MissingDependency("The 'elasticsearch' backend requires the installation of 'requests'.")
>   haystack.exceptions.MissingDependency: The 'elasticsearch' backend requires the installation of 'requests'.

I've installed all the packages needed to run those apps however is asking about requests, What is it about?

Comment: BTW How you have installed django-haystack?

Comment: Are you certain that requests is installed? Try running `pip install requests`. Also, if you aren't running this in a virtualenv, might be a good idea so you can better manage dependencies and avoid conflicts across projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just install [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) module through pip this error should go away.

Comment: Unfortunalty requests is installed (even uninstalled/reinstalled in virtualenv to make sure), and it still don't work.

Comment: Should have been problem with virtualenv. Make sure the environment is activated or you should install requests where the haystack is installed.

Answer (score 24):

just do

```
pip install pyelasticsearch
```

Comment: This trick worked for me. Aforementioned command installed following packages:
_Installing collected packages: certifi, urllib3, elasticsearch, simplejson, six, pyelasticsearch_

So problem must be due to missing dependecies ( urllib3 I strongly suspect)

Answer (score 0):

pip install "elasticsearch>=7,<8"