# Django Haystack - MissingDependency

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have checked these posts without success:

- [Can't get Elasticsearch working with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28257502/cant-get-elasticsearch-working-with-django)
- [Error: The 'elasticsearch' backend requires the installation of 'requests'. How do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412045/error-the-elasticsearch-backend-requires-the-installation-of-requests-how)
- [haystack.exceptions.MissingDependency: The 'elasticsearch' backend requires the installation of 'elasticsearch'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33279574/haystack-exceptions-missingdependency-the-elasticsearch-backend-requires-the)

my requirements.txt

```
appdirs==1.4.3
bcrypt==3.1.3
certifi==2017.4.17
cffi==1.10.0
chardet==3.0.4
construct==2.5.3
dj-database-url==0.4.2
Django==1.10.7
django-cors-headers==2.0.2
django-debug-toolbar==1.8
django-field-history==0.6.0
django-haystack==2.6.1
django-pandas==0.4.1
djangorestframework==3.6.2
drf-haystack==1.6.1
elasticsearch==2.4.1
future==0.16.0
gunicorn==19.7.1
idna==2.5
numpy==1.12.1
olefile==0.44
packaging==16.8
pandas==0.20.1
pefile==2016.3.28
Pillow==4.1.1
psycopg2==2.7.1
pycparser==2.17
pyparsing==2.2.0
python-dateutil==2.6.0
python-ptrace==0.9.2
pytz==2017.2
requests==2.17.3
simplejson==3.10.0
six==1.10.0
sqlparse==0.2.3
urllib3==1.21.1
whitenoise==3.3.0
```

my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    #===external apps===
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'corsheaders',
    'field_history',
    'elasticsearch',
    'haystack',
    'debug_toolbar',
]
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch2_backend.Elasticsearch2SearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://192.168.99.100:3276/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'crm',
    },
}
```

When trying to run `python manage.py rebuild_index` I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\kazi_\Documents\GitHub\esar_drf\venv\lib\site-packages\haystack\backends\elasticsearch2_backend.py", line 9, in <module>
    from haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend import ElasticsearchSearchBackend, ElasticsearchSearchQuery

File "C:\Users\kazi_\Documents\GitHub\esar_drf\venv\lib\site-packages\haystack\backends\elasticsearch_backend.py", line 33, in <module>
    raise MissingDependency("The 'elasticsearch' backend requires the installation of 'elasticsearch'. Please refer to the documentation.")
haystack.exceptions.MissingDependency: The 'elasticsearch' backend requires the installation of 'elasticsearch'. Please refer to the documentation.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer is quite simple. I had a naming conflict, as one of my packages was named elasticsearch.